# Could not parse Master URL

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

i will be thankful if anyone answer my question.
part of my code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    SparkConf conf= new SparkConf().setAppName("AirPollution").setMaster("yarn");
    SparkContext context=new SparkContext(conf);
```

how can i fix this error?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'yarn'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find the soultion. any body that has this problem should add spark-yarn.jar to the build path. the important issue is that IT SHOULD BE THE LAST VERSION, IF YOU USE SPARK 2+. for example spark-yarn2.11 worked for me

Comment: Thanks very much!

Answer (score 5):

According to the recent Spark code in the master, this should work. By default, Spark will use client deploy mode if you do not set the `spark.submit.deployMode` configuration parameter.

However, this will not work in Spark 1.6.x. If you use Spark 1.6.x, you will have to explicitly specify your master URL as "yarn-cluster" or "yarn-client".

Consider also using `spark-submit` since it will help you to avoid setting some configuration parameters in the code (e.g. master URL). As a result, you will be able to use another cluster manager without the need to recompile your program.

Comment: thanks for your answer.I use Spark 2.0.0. so if i use spark-submit, I shouldn't have cons object in my code? its not possible to create this object without setting the Masterurl. what should i do ?

Comment: @marjan spark-submit allows you to avoid hard-coding certain configurations in a SparkConf. You can create SparkConf object without the master URL. [This](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html) and [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamically-loading-spark-properties) should be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 3):

I am able to resolve this issue by including below Spark Project Yarn Dependency into my Scala Project.

My VM Spark version is 2.3.0 . Scala - 2.11.0

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-yarn_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Referred below link
https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/36354/eclipse-to-sandbox-1.html